# Wrote a PHP code to take user registration time and add extra seconds but it doesn't work

Tags: php, cron

So i made cron job, which takes users registration time and if x time have passed cron job then sends him a reminder.

All parts are working reminder are send each time the cron job run, and is sent once.

But code never adds extra seconds to the registration time, and is sent even that time haven't passed yet. So if i set to check if 10minutes has passed but i run cron job 1min each, all users gets messages after 1 second

Code is here:

```
$filter = $staticMessage->filter.' AND join_date_time+1800 >= "'.$time.'"';
```

Any ideas?

From coments

```
'$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO chat (s_id,r_id,time,reminder_time,message,fake,online_day,auto) VALUES ('".$randomSender->id."','".$userId."','".$time."','".$time."','".$message."',0,0,2)");

                        if($userLastaccess+3900 <= time()){
                            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO staticmessages_sent (static_id,fake_id,r_id,answer,send_date,email_out) VALUES ('".$staticMessage->id."','".$randomSender->id."','".$userId."','0','".$time."',1)");
                            chatMailNotification($userId,$message,$randomSender->id);
                        } else {
                            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO staticmessages_sent (static_id,fake_id,r_id,answer,send_date) VALUES ('".$staticMessage->id."','".$randomSender->id."','".$userId."','0','".$time."')");
                        }

                        if($userLastaccess+3600 <= time()){
                            $push['time'] = date("H:i", time());
                            $event = 'chat'.$userId.$randomSender->id;
                            $noti= 'notification'.$userId;
                            $push['id'] = $randomSender->id;
                            $push['type'] = 1;
                            $push['icon'] = profilePhoto($randomSender->id);
                            $push['name'] = $randomSender->username;
                            $push['photo'] = 0;
                            $push['action'] = 'message';
                            if(is_numeric($sm['plugins']['pusher']['id'])){ 
                                $sm['push']->trigger($sm['plugins']['pusher']['key'], $event, $push);
                            }'
```

Comment: What is `$time`? What is the final SQL statement being generated? What datatype is the `join_date_time` column?

Comment: join_date_time is just Unix time stamp f.e: 1651584252, Final should be Join date + added extra seconds.

Comment: _"Final should be..."_ But is it really? Can you show us *exactly* what the final SQL statement is?

Comment: Kmoser added to the POST its to long to add to comment :)

Comment: You are open for [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: I would start by removing the `"` from ` "'.$time.'"'`. You are comparing integer against a string. That can always cause issues.

Comment: @P4rm3san It's not clear how the coded you added relates to the original code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this (Assuming userLastaccess is datetime):

```
$timenow = date("Y-n-j H:i:s");
$userLastaccess = strtotime ('+3900 second',$userLastaccess ); 

 if($userLastaccess <= $timenow){
```

And then for security you can use these two functions that improve code injection protection a bit: `htmlspecialchars` and `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: I think the problem is here: $filter = $staticMessage->filter.' AND join_date_time+300 >= "'.$time.'"';                       Join  date is when user registered + 300 secs should be less or equal to current time. I think i am doing something wrong with this part "'.$time.'"';  ?